# Media query font-size not working

Tags: html, css, media

I searched, but didn't find anything similar to my problem.

```css
#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  background: url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat top left;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#navigation a {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #F2B704;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navigation a:hover {
  color: #D78E02;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #navigation a {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <a href="#galerija">GALERIJA</a>
  <a href="#festival">FESTIVAL</a>
  <a href="#kontakt">KONTAKT</a>
</div>
```

Media query doesn't result in changing my `font-size` on smaller screen width, it still stays at `15px`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: specify a !important...@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #navigation a {
    font-size: 10px !important;
  }
}

Comment: #navigation a {
    font-size: 10px !important;
  } in media query

Comment: @yjs `!important` is a bad practice.

Comment: @alirezasafian If it is bad practice, then we can call appropriate css style sheet for different device-width.... eg: <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 800px)" href="800.css" /> but in above case - !important only works!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use `max-device-width: 480px` in your media query so you have to have[`meta viewport`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) to browser detect the width of devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

There is not wrong with your code. You can change `max-device-width: 480px` to `max-width: 480px` to see your code works. You only need to add meta viewport in your `head` tag.

[Jsffidle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/v7jqfn0g/1/)

Comment: This one worked best, tnx, I thought I needed that meta code only for responsive pages, not a simple navigation transformation :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
@media  (max-width: 480px) {
#navigation a {
  font-size: 10px !important;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 #navigation a {
  font-size: 10px !important;
 } 
}
```

Comment: Explain your answer.[From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10628265).

Answer (score 0):

4 years later...

Sorry for the delay in responding, Igor.  Thanks for waiting. 8)

In case you are still interested in an answer to this, or if others who find this are, I tested your code and found that if I change the media tag option from "max-device-width:" to "max-width:", the font size changed.  But I guess it depends on the device size vs. the browser size, so this might not solve it for you.

If that doesn't solve it, try experimenting with larger browser widths like "max-width: 800" or whatever, to ensure your browser width is definitely triggering the media query.

Let me know how you get on.